# django foreign key lookup aggregate data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a tool inventory/tracking system. My current question is how can I gather the total number of tools that are currently checked out, and subtract that amount from the total quantity that I have of that tool. So that I can display a quantity on hand. So that a user can make sure that the tool is currently in the shop and is not checked out by someone borrowing it.

Models:

```
class ActiveTransactionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveTransactionManager, self).get_queryset().filter(CheckInDate = None)

class Tool(models.Model):
    ToolID=models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key = True, unique=True, db_column='ToolID')
    Quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    Location=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    CategoryID=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)

    objects=models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        managed=True
        db_table='Tool'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ToolID

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ToolSearch:toolSearchResults", kwargs={"pk": self.ToolID})

class ToolCheckIn(models.Model):
    CheckOutID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ToolID=models.ForeignKey(Tool, db_column='ToolID', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    PartyID=models.ForeignKey(Borrower, db_column='PartyID', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    Quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    CheckOutDate=models.DateField(null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    CheckInDate=models.DateField(null=True)
    Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)

    objects=ActiveTransactionManager()

    class Meta:
        managed=True
        db_table='ToolTransaction'
        ordering=('CheckOutID',)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.CheckOutID)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ToolSearch:toolCheckin", kwargs={"pk": self.CheckOutID})
```

View:

```
def tool_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance = None
        pk = (request.POST.get('toolid', 'Nothing Found'))
        instance = Tool.objects.all().filter(ToolID__icontains=pk)
        context = {
            "ToolID": instance
        }
        return render(request, "toolsearchresults.html", context)

    return render(request, "toolsearch.html")
```

I was receiving this error: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
I have removed the line of code in my view that is listed above that was causing the error: 
queryset = ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID_id__icontains=pk)

Not sure if I can achieve this from the ORM or if I will need to write some raw sql to achieve this. I am currently using a MYSQL DB.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you mistakenly wrote `Tool` instead of `ToolCheckIn` in the **View** you've shown us, coz later on you've mentioned the query as ToolCheckIn.objects.all(). Is it so? Coz then I might have the answer.

Comment: Tool.objects.all is for me retrieving all the data about the tools that match with the searched ToolID. I will need a ToolTransaction object as well so that I can add up the quantity of ToolTransactions for each ToolID and subtract it from the Total Quantity of each ToolID in Tool. Then I can subtract the Quantity of ToolTransaction tools from my total quantity to tell the user how many tools are currently in stock. If that makes sense. Let me know if more clarification would help.

Comment: All i'm asking is that have you made a **typo** while writing this question of yours here on stackoverflow in the `tool_search` function in the line `instance = Tool.objects.all().filter(ToolID__icontains=pk)` ? It must be **ToolCheckIn.objects.all()** instead of **Tool.objects.all()** ?? This is my doubt.

Comment: Yes, I will have something like query = ToolCheckIn.objects.all. I just don't know how to go about pulling the quantity for matching ToolIDs inside of the ToolCheckIn.objects.all queryset that it returns. We can treat the Tool.objects as a type certainly, I had just removed the ToolCheckIn.objects line from the code since it was causing an error to be thrown. ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID_id__icontains=pk) was located right below the Tool.objects.all

Comment: Firstly, you should avoid using **db_column** specially for the unique primary key as django uses its own built in primary key which are **integers**. In your case, you are use a `char` type primary key, and then the same will be used for the foreign key in `ToolCheckIn` as well, but i'm not so whether django handles this foreign key to be of `char` type or not, and hence raises the **lookup** error as you can use **icontains** for a string but not for an integer value.

Comment: Did you try `ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__ToolID__icontains=pk)` ?
Basically in the above you are going to use the **icontains** filter on the `ToolID` field of the `Tool` model instead of using that query on the foreign key of `ToolCheckIn` model.

Comment: That did work. Here was the code I used. query = ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__ToolID__contains=pk), 
I'm an idiot and used icontains and not contains. I am also able to iterate through the queryset and get my totals for tool quantity. I need to do some more tweaking to make sure it is for the correct tool but this was SUPER helpful. Thank you!

total=0
  for q in query:
   total += q.Quantity

Comment: Happy to help. :) I'll probably add this explanation as the answer for others who might face the same problem as yours.

Comment: Hey @furiousGeorge, can you also try the query ` query = ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__contains=pk‌​)` i.e., simply checking the **contains** check on the `ToolID` field of ToolCheckIn model . I'm curious to know whether this will work or not. This will give us the answer of whether Django takes care of foreign key not being an integer value or not.

Comment: @Ankush R I will test that and let you know when I get a chance tonight. I was wondering if you could elaborate a bit more on why I had to use ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__ToolID...) Why wouldn't it be Tool__ToolID since it is the tool model? I just don't understand exactly how the filtering for the models works.

Comment: I just checked and Related Field got invalid lookup: contains is the error I receive when I tried ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__contains=pk), I even tried icontains. Still had the exact same error.

Comment: Okay firstly coming to your doubt. `ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__ToolID__contains=p‌​k)` means that you are making a contains query on the `ToolID` field of the model `Tool` which is related as a foreign key in the model `ToolCheckIn` and coincidently you named the field in as `ToolId` in `ToolCheckIn` model as well. The first 'ToolID` in the query corresponds to the `ToolID` field of the `ToolCheckIn` model and then the second `ToolID` corresponds to the `ToolID` field in the model `Tool`.

Comment: If you had to make a query on say `Location` of the model `Tool` using the foreign key in the `ToolCheckIn` model, then your query would look like `ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__Location__contains=p‌‌​​k)`.
The double underscore is sort of a path or door to the model from where the relation or foreign key is coming from. Suppose the field name for the foreign key in the `ToolCheckIn` model would have been say `furiousGeorge`, then the query would have been `ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(furiousGeorge__Location__contains=p‌​k)`
So that foreign key is the door to the model `Tool`

Comment: I hope the above example will clear your doubt regarding how to make queries on relation. :) But the interesting thing to note here is that as you said, the **contains** query didn't work in case of 'ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__contains=p‌‌​​k)` which probably means that either Django does some formatting or creates some hash while keeping the foreign keys, as I've used the `equality` condition on the foreign key field successfully with no errors. Hence probably Django doesn't supports direct `contains`  query on the foreign keys but supports `equality` (which it obviously should)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the important information from comments to the answer.

In your case the suitable contains query will be

```
ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__ToolID__contains=p‌​k)
```

Basically if the field name of the foreign key in your `ToolCheckIn` model would have been say `stackoverflow`, then the query would have been

```
ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(stackoverflow__ToolID__contains=p‌​k)
```

The above means that you are making a contains query on the `ToolID` field of model `Tool` using the foreign key `stackoverflow` in the model `ToolCheckIn`.

If you would have made a **contains** query on say field `Location` of the model `Tool` then your query would have looked something like this

```
ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(stackoverflow__Location__contains=p‌​k)
```

The foreign key is sort of a door to the `model` from where the foreign key or the relation is coming from and the **double underscore** is the path to the same.

I hope this clears it for you.

Though the interesting thing to note is that why the below didn't work

```
ToolCheckIn.objects.all().filter(ToolID__contains=p‌​k)
```

Even the Docs don't provide any information regarding how a foreign key is kept in the table. Whether it is formatted or hashed before storing so as to why the **contains** query gave an `Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains` error or whether Django doesn't supports the **contains** lookup on foreign keys directly, only supporting the **equality** lookup i.e., assuming the foreign key to always be an **integer** type as the foreign key is the **primary key** of the model from where it comes, and by default, if you don't provide any primary key, then Django makes its own **primary key** which of the **int** type. Hence, not covering the case when the primary key can be field of **Char** type, which brings with it the possibility of a **contains** lookup as **contains** won't work on **int** type.

That's what I think as I didn't find much relevant info on the internet regarding the same.

Comment: you can use just ```ToolCheckIn.objects.filter(ToolID__contains=p‌​k)``` without calling all objects :)